# Failed to register 'filter errorPageFilterRegistration' on the servlet context

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have developed a springboot REST API that works correctly on the **embebbed tomcat** of my IDE but when I try to deploy its WAR file into a **true tomcat** (10.1.7) inside of a docker I get the following error:

```
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.1.7
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.167 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 27 2023 20:25:27 UTC
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.167 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.1.7.0
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.167 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.168 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.2.0-26-generic
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.168 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.168 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /opt/java/openjdk
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.168 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           17.0.6+10
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.168 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Eclipse Adoptium
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.168 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.168 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.180 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.180 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.180 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.180 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.180 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.180 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.180 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.181 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.181 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.181 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.181 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.181 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.181 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.192 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [2.0.3] using APR version [1.7.0].
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.202 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022]
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.403 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.429 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [488] milliseconds
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.457 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.457 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.7]
04-Sep-2023 12:05:36.472 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/theapp.war]
04-Sep-2023 12:05:37.629 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.1)


2023-09-04T12:05:38.129Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.theapp.theappApplication     : Starting theappApplication v1.0 using Java 17.0.6 with PID 1 (/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/theapp/WEB-INF/classes started by root in /usr/local/tomcat)
2023-09-04T12:05:38.131Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.theapp.theappApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-04T12:05:38.748Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 587 ms
2023-09-04T12:05:39.071Z DEBUG 1 --- [           main] swordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder : No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.
2023-09-04T12:05:39.211Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@23389e2b, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1c0cba60, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@6225c800, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1acf7db2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4e791e53, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@5ace5b0e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@17f43f4a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@143abb21, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@34b294c4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@71d92487, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@15d41953]
2023-09-04T12:05:39.581Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.theapp.theappApplication     : Started theappApplication in 1.786 seconds (process running for 3.892)
2023-09-04T12:05:39.585Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.theapp.ServletInitializer        : Root context already created (using as parent).

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.1)


2023-09-04T12:05:39.606Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.theapp.ServletInitializer        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-04T12:05:39.737Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 128 ms
2023-09-04T12:05:39.748Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
2023-09-04T12:05:39.753Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

2023-09-04T12:05:39.772Z 
ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:602) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:174) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:96) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4875) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:975) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1949) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:776) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1656) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347) ~[bootstrap.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478) ~[bootstrap.jar:10.1.7]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to register 'filter errorPageFilterRegistration' on the servlet context. Possibly already registered?
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DynamicRegistrationBean.register(DynamicRegistrationBean.java:122) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean.onStartup(RegistrationBean.java:52) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:236) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:192) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 49 common frames omitted


04-Sep-2023 12:05:39.777 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/theapp.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:975)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1949)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:776)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1656)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/theapp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:602)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:174)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to register 'filter errorPageFilterRegistration' on the servlet context. Possibly already registered?
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DynamicRegistrationBean.register(DynamicRegistrationBean.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean.onStartup(RegistrationBean.java:52)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:236)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:192)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
```

Based on the error stack I have searched about ErrorPageFilter and I have found several references about deactivating the ErrorPageFilter, but I am not sure whether that is the root cause of the error.

In order to deactivate the ErrorPageFilter I have found a couple of options. The first one is about adding this code in the properties file, but it doesn't work:

`logging.level.org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter=off`

Another way is adding this code, but to be honest I don't know where to add it:

```
Bean
public ErrorPageFilter errorPageFilter() {
    return new ErrorPageFilter();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean disableSpringBootErrorFilter(ErrorPageFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

Can someone give me a clue about this?
Thanks in advance!

**U P D A T E**

The POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.theapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>theapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>theapp</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>theapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The properties file:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=REALM_URI
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=JWK_URI
jwt.auth.converter.resource-id=the-client
jwt.auth.converter.principal-attribute=preferred_username
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
logging.level.=DEBUG
```

The SpringBootApplication java file:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class theappApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(theappApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The springboot ServletInitializer:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override 
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(theappApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Security configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, KeycloakAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2ResourceServer) -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt((jwt) -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())))
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt((jwt) -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter)));
        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri("CERTS_URI").build();
    } 

    @Component
    static class KeycloakAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>> {
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
        public List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
            final var realmAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("realm_access", Map.of());
            final var roles = (List<String>) realmAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());
            return roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList(); 
        }
    }
    
    @Component
    static class KeycloakAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken> {
        private final KeycloakAuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter;

        @Override
        public JwtAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
            return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt), jwt.getClaimAsString(StandardClaimNames.PREFERRED_USERNAME));
        }

        public KeycloakAuthenticationConverter (KeycloakAuthoritiesConverter the_authoritiesConverter) {
            this.authoritiesConverter = the_authoritiesConverter;
        }
    }    

}
```

Part of the REST controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired()
    UserService userService;
    
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('myrole')")
    @GetMapping("/example1")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getString(){
        return userService.getString();
    }

 ...   
 
}
```

As I stated, it is a quite simple REST API. Let me know in case more code is needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added most of the files, hope it helps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have both `theappApplication` and `ServletInitializer` that extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`. This will result in your application being started up twice. You can see this from the logs as the Spring banner appears twice. This duplicate initialization will result in an attempt to register the same filter twice which fails.

From what you've shared thus far, you can delete `ServletInitializer` and your app should start correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! I supposed that the double execution of Tomcat was the root problem, but didn't know the reason of it. Thanks!